# How Can I Add Caliburn.Micro To a Portable Class Library (PCL)?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, caliburn.micro, portable-class-library, windows-phone-8.1

In Visual Studio 2013 Update 2, I am developing an application that targets both Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1. I am using Caliburn.Micro 2.0.0-beta2.

In my solution, there are two projects: ProjWPA81 targeting Windows Phone 8.1, and ProjWin81 targeting Windows 8.1.

I want to create a Portable Class Library (PCL) that targets Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 (portable-win81+wpa81) to be able to share view models between the above-mentioned projects.

However, after creating the PCL, when I try to add reference to Caliburn.Micro 2.0.0-beta2 through the NuGet Package Manager, the operation fails with the following message:

> Could not install package 'Caliburn.Micro 2.0.0-beta2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-win81+wpa81', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

It seems, it is not possible. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caliburn.Micro.Core is for the use with PCLs.